# Why does the snowflake python connector hang indefinitely without throwing an error?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the snowflake python connector (snowflake-connector-python) to upload data from an SFTP location. This runs every week and mostly works without any issues. Sometimes, however, the initiating login request fails without error. Below is the message I see in the cmd window:

```
"Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again..."
```

When this login request fails , I get stuck here indefinitely and pressing CTRL + C doesn't seem to do anything.

I have created a new environment with just the bare minimum needed to run the snowflake connector and the problem persists - so I don't think there is an issue with any conflicting libraries.

Has anyone had similar issues with the connector/know what the issue is? OR has anyone come up with a work around (like a timer which will cancel the login request after some time if no connection)?

Any help is appreciated!